# when I hover over the div

Tags: html, css

when I hover over the div, I want the effect of the cover art not to overflow out of the box and to act as it does in the profile picture. They are currently moving when they pass them one by one, can you help

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: inset -2px 2px 20px 1px #0a031a7a;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: background-color .15s, box-shadow .15s;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: gray;
  width: 460px;
}

.kingbox:not(.not-hoverable) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.kingbox:hover>.queenbox:hover {
  background-color: rgba(9, 20, 26, 0.8);
}

.kingbox .queenbox:hover {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.075);
}

.queenbox {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  width: 460px;
}

.princebox:hover {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

.princebox {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -40px;
  left: 25px;
}

.img1 {
  width: 50px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.kingbox {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px transparent;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: background-color .15s, box-shadow .15s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card kingbox">
  <img class="queenbox" src="https://cdn.ntvspor.net/083b3a697b6f48b48e59e770630cfdd5.jpg?crop=0,48,940,577&w=1200&mode=crop" alt="" style="" loading="lazy">
  <div class="princebox" style="background: url(https://sportpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Cristiano-Ronaldo-sportpng-3.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: center;">
  </div>
  <div class="x" style="padding: 15px;">
    <h6 class="card-title">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/FIFA_series_logo.png" class="img1">
    </h6>
    <p class="card-text f-s-12">Fifa 07...</p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse float-right">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: I think adding `overflow:hidden;` to the `.card` class will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

overflow:hidden as suggested seems to do the trick

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: inset -2px 2px 20px 1px #0a031a7a;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: background-color .15s, box-shadow .15s;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: gray;
  width: 460px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.kingbox:not(.not-hoverable) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.kingbox:hover>.queenbox:hover {
  background-color: rgba(9, 20, 26, 0.8);
}

.kingbox .queenbox:hover {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.075);
}

.queenbox {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  width: 460px;
}

.princebox:hover {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

.princebox {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -40px;
  left: 25px;
}

.img1 {
  width: 50px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.kingbox {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px transparent;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: background-color .15s, box-shadow .15s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card kingbox">
  <img class="queenbox" src="https://cdn.ntvspor.net/083b3a697b6f48b48e59e770630cfdd5.jpg?crop=0,48,940,577&w=1200&mode=crop" alt="" style="" loading="lazy">
  <div class="princebox" style="background: url(https://sportpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Cristiano-Ronaldo-sportpng-3.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: center;">
  </div>
  <div class="x" style="padding: 15px;">
    <h6 class="card-title">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/FIFA_series_logo.png" class="img1">
    </h6>
    <p class="card-text f-s-12">Fifa 07...</p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse float-right">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, firstly thx for answer, but I also want the image not to overflow below. And when Fifa is 07 AND the Button is where it is, I want the whole highlight to work

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: inset -2px 2px 20px 1px #0a031a7a;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: background-color .15s, box-shadow .15s;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: gray;
  width: 460px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.kingbox:not(.not-hoverable) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.kingbox:hover>.queenbox:hover {
  background-color: rgba(9, 20, 26, 0.8);
}

.kingbox .queenbox:hover {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(1.075);
}

.queenbox {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  width: 460px;
}

.princebox:hover {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

.princebox {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -40px;
  left: 25px;
}

.img1 {
  width: 50px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.kingbox {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px transparent;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: background-color .15s, box-shadow .15s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card kingbox">
  <img class="queenbox" src="https://cdn.ntvspor.net/083b3a697b6f48b48e59e770630cfdd5.jpg?crop=0,48,940,577&w=1200&mode=crop" alt="" style="" loading="lazy">
  <div class="princebox" style="background: url(https://sportpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Cristiano-Ronaldo-sportpng-3.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: center;">
  </div>
  <div class="x" style="padding: 15px;">
    <h6 class="card-title">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/FIFA_series_logo.png" class="img1">
    </h6>
    <p class="card-text f-s-12">Fifa 07...</p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse float-right">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi, firstly thanks. When Fifa is 07 AND the Button is hover where it is, I want all the hover to work